# Validation if you're using the correct DB

Tags: sql, validation, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there a way to have a validation script before continuing a script?

So

```
DECLARE @strServernameToClear as VarChar(100)
DECLARE @strCurrentServer as VarChar(100)
DECLARE @strDatabaseToClear as VarChar (100)
DECLARE @strDatabase as VarChar (100)


SET @strDatabase = (SELECT @@database) << THIS IS WHERE IM HAVING TROUBLE. How to indicate which database it is running against

IF @strCurrentServer <> @strServernameToClear
BEGIN
    PRINT '*****************WARNING *****************' 
    PRINT 'WRONG DB NAME: This server is: ' + @strCurrentServer 
    PRINT 'If this is the correct server, set @strServernameToClear to ' + @strCurrentServer
    RETURN 

END

ELSE

EXECUTE ORDER 66
```

Comment: what database server are you using? each will have different syntax to get the current database name...

Comment: This is best handled at the application level.

Comment: It's a 2008R2 Server

Comment: Why not call a user-defined function or stored procedure to perform the validation.  This could then be called in-script or in-app as you see fit.

Comment: @@[Current Database] ?

Comment: I'm sorry but im more comfortable doing it this way. Just need to know how to reference the current database that the script is being ran on.

Answer (score 0):

I think this'll work for you:

```
select @strDatabase = d.name
from sys.sysprocesses p
join sys.databases d on d.database_id = p.dbid
where p.spid = @@SPID
```